# A question about a certain type of primes

Tags: number-theory

This is a computational problem, I don't know how much theoretical.
With Pari, just for fun, I found:
\begin{array}{c|c}
2  & 19\\
\hline 
3 &  29\\
\hline 
5 &  487\\
\hline
7 &22053404036884180513958627370176317218668443714432289646932414656004065291773402535727759 \\
\hline
11  & 33223
\end{array}
The first column is the $n$-th prime $p_n$, whereas the second column is the prime $\lfloor p_n*\pi^k\rfloor=A(n)$ with the smallest possible $k$ positive integer, i mean k is the smallest positive integer for which $A(n)$ is prime. My question is: can exist two or more primes $A(n)$'s which are the same?

Comment: @Brian I mean the smallest possible k for which A(n) is prime

Comment: Is the existence of k obvious?

Comment: @Lior B-S no surely not obvious, but my question is if there are two or more A(n)'s which are the same.

Comment: These type of questions tend to be very difficult. How far did you check it on a computer? Maybe you will get lucky.

Comment: @Lior B-S up to 3000 it seems that the existence of k is Always certain, but i don't know if there are two A(n)'s equal

Comment: Well already for p=7, you got a very large k. BTW where did the question come from ?

Comment: @Lior B-S from nothing...

Answer (score 1):

$p_1 = 991, p_2=9781$ will both return $A(p_i)=30727$ for $k_1=3$ and $k_2=1$

I used a very simple brute force algo, looking only for values of $k$ small enough.

**Edit** other examples
$$\begin{array}{c|cc|cc}
A(p_i)&p_1&k_1&p_2&k_2\\
\hline
30727&9781&1&991&3\\
200579&20323&2&6469&3\\
129499&41221&1&13121&2\\
138283&44017&1&14011&2\\
170063&54133&1&17231&2\\
182617&58129&1&18503&2\\
593429&60127&2&19139&3\\
684091&69313&2&22063&3\\
237689&75659&1&24083&2\\
252869&80491&1&25621&2\\
293729&93497&1&29761&2\\
\end{array}$$

Comment: any other solution?

Comment: 9781/991 is infact a good approximation of pi^2

Comment: yes there are plenty, even without looking too hard. I'll edit my post