# Is there a prime of the given form?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

Here : [A question about a certain type of primes](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3158288/a-question-about-a-certain-type-of-primes)

primes of the form $$\lfloor p\cdot \pi^n \rfloor$$ with a prime $\ p\ $ and a positive integer $\ n\ $ play a role. For the prime $\ p=19543\ $ , according to my calculations, a prime of this form must satisfy $\ n\ge 21\ 000\ $, hence have more than $\ 10\ 000\ $ digits.

> Does a prime of the form $$\lfloor 19543 \cdot \pi^n\rfloor$$ exist and if yes, what is the smallest positive integer $\ n\ $ doing the job ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simple brute force search in Maple reveals that smallest positive integer $n$ is $25536$, the probable prime being

$$\lfloor 19543 \cdot \pi^{25536}\rfloor = \underbrace{3236982484 \dots 5580309289}_{12700 \text{ digits}}$$

Perhaps someone can verify primality (at least probable).

Comment: Any reason to doubt Maple ? Anyway, I used the Miller-Rabin-test with $10$ random bases and the number passed it, hence is probably prime.

Comment: Do you know whether it uses the Miller-Rabin-test or the BPSW-test ?

Comment: The latter in fact is extremely reliable. Although infinite many counterexmaples are expected, noone could construct or find one.To prove the number to be prime however will not be easy (Primo is probably the best way).

Comment: Good question, the documentation mentions "one strong pseudo-primality test and one Lucas test", and Miller-Rabin wiki mentions Maple uses it, but I'm not sure how that can be trusted. I'm not familiar with BPSW-test but perhaps it could be the "one strong" test.

Comment: Then it probably IS the BPSW test, it combines two tests as you mention.

Comment: Yes, just found on the wiki for the test this: The following computer algebra systems and software packages use some version of the Baillie–PSW primality test.

Maple's isprime function ...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/91477/discussion-between-peter-and-sil).

Comment: @Sil Out of curiosity and need to upgrade my own, wanted to ask on what computer hardware did you run your brute force check of this magnitude and what was the run time?

Comment: @NilotpalKantiSinha I've got Intel i7-4790 3.6 GHz quad core. I am usually using parallel computation (otherwise Maple engine is by default using single thread), so in this case using 6 threads it got from $n=1$ to $n=25536$ in about 70 minutes.